# Jacobian of Matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule, jacobian

I would like to compute the Jacobian matrix of the following product
$$
   g(x) = \text{diag}\left(A^T f(x) \right) B^T f(x),
$$
where $\text{diag}(v)$ denotes the diagonal matrix formed by placing $v$ on its main diagonal. Matrices $A,B$ are both $m \times \ell$ and do not depend on $x$. The function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ maps $x$ to $[x^T \quad 1\; \cdots \; 1]$. This computation should be fairly simple by product rule and chain rule, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to deal with the $\text{diag}$ operation. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: This is the same as $g(x) = \left(A^Tf(x)\right)\circ\left(B^Tf(x)\right)$ where $\circ$ is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: **PS:** If the dimensions are as written, then $A^\intercal$ is an $m\times\ell$ matrix, and $f(x)$ is a $1\times m$ matrix (a row vector), so therefore the multiplication cannot even happen .

Comment: @GrahamKemp sorry about this, fixed.